# raphael js - font italic in IE

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am having problems with text in IE - it is showing up as italic regardless what I try - here is my code can anyone help

```
var clear_text = paper.text(50, 260, "Dept A");
clear_text.attr("fill", "#000");
clear_text.attr({ "font-size": 16, "font-family": "Times New Roman,Georgia,Serif", "font-weight": "bold", "font-style": "normal"});
```

found out that this only is on IE8 64bit

Comment: Can you clarify which version of IE you are using? It could be a limitation or bug with VML in IE8

Comment: I think it must be a bug with IE8 64bit as 32bit and IE6 and 7 seem correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed - IE8 64bit version has known bugs with VML that causes this.